# including bash "script" command inside a script

Tags: shell, logging, include

I need to set some variables in my shell and format the shell prompt before I do a certain task every time. Also I need to record my actions.

At the moment, I'm running a script, collecting all the information it needs (partly by user input) and it sets the new shell prompt and the variables. Then I start the recording with `script $var-actionlog-$anothervar-1.log`. The variables used are set during the call of `my_script.sh`. Then, since a new shell spawned by the script command, I need to call `source my_script.sh` again.

Is there a way that I can include the `script`-part directly in `my_script.sh` so that I don't have to enter everything twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `export` in your initial setup script to make the local variables global.  For example, your setup script, `my_script.sh` could be:

```
#!/bin/sh
# A startup script

export var="world"
export PS1="\u@\h \w> "

echo "Please enter a number, followed by [ENTER]:"
read num

export anothervar="$num"

script $var-actionlog-$anothervar-1.log
```

Then, once the script has started, to confirm you can run:

```
echo var=$var, anothervar=$anothervar
```

If you want to set a different shell prompt (`$PS1`) in your `my_script.sh`, to be used by the typescript, make sure that you are not setting `$PS1` in `~/.bashrc`.  The typescript, `script $var-actionlog-$anothervar-1.log`, calls `~/.bashrc` every time and will override your prompt variable, `$PS1`.  To set your prompt for log-in shells only, set this in `~/.bash_login`.

Comment: Great, thanks! That works almost. Only the Shell prompt doesn't get set as defined in the script. Is it possible that the script will spawn a shell with a specific shell prompt? I don't want to have this shell prompt all the time, so it'd be nice not to set it fix in `~.bash_login`.

Comment: Yes. Is your `$PS1` being set in ~/.bashrc? If so, you'll want to remove your original one and move it to either /etc/bashrc or bash_profile. Check out this [explanation](http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html).  Otherwise, if you set `$PS1` in your script, it should work.